# How to call custom.js file in for loop and i want pass some argument with this js

Tags: javascript, php

How to call customs.js file in for loop and i want pass some argument with this js,And how to retrieve this var in JavaScript file.

```
      for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{


  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://localhost/customs.js?var=test'">
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this would be to include your custom.js in the html of the webpage and wrap it's code in a function to which you can pass a variable, like so:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://localhost/customs.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Your HTML -->
        <script>
            <?php 
                 for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
                      echo "custom(".$myvar.");";
                 }
            ?>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then in your custom.js file you can do this:

```
function custom(input){
    //Do something
}
```

I should note that you should be careful inserting unsanitized PHP into html directly. For more info, see: [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)